# Expressing a matrix of rank $k$ as the product of matrices of rank $k$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Since $A\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ is an $m\times n$ matrix of rank $k$. Can $A$ be expressed as $A=BC$ where $B$ is an $m\times k$ matrix of rank $k$, and $C$ is a $k\times n$ matrix of rank $k$?

I know that since $A$ has rank $k$, then $A=PJ_kQ$
where
$$
J_k=\begin{bmatrix}
I_k & 0_{k,n-k}\\
0_{m-k,k} & 0_{m-k,n-k}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $P$ is an invertible $m\times m$ matrix, and $Q$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix. However, I can't seem to fiddle this into two matrices like $B$ and $C$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the [rank factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization) of a matrix. The wikipedia page provdies a rather detailed examination of the factorization so I will not go into detail. I will simply summarize the main result

**Theorem:** Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix of rank $r$. Then there exists $m \times r$ matrix $C$ and $r\times n$ matrix $F$, each of rank $r$, such that $A = CF$. Moreover, one such decomposition can be obtained by taking $C$ as the reduced row echelon form of $A$ with non-pivot columns removed and taking $F$ as the reduced row echelon form of $A$ with zero rows removed.